# FlexSlider Should be simple

Tags: javascript, flexslider

How come this doesn't work?

```
var slider = $('#carslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        itemWidth: 225,
        directionNav: true, 
        move: 1
    });
console.log(slider.slides)
```

I get Undefined ? The slider is working just fine.

Comment: `slides` is a property of the `slider` object, not of its host (jQuery object). Try querying `slider.data('flexslider').slides` instead.

Comment: How do I gain access to the slider object once its instantiated?